# "SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted" when activating rtl8723bs driver in embedded Linux on LicheePi board based on Allwinner V3s?

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, debian-buster

I'm trying to test a rtl8723bs sdio wifi module on a development board (LicheePi, Allwinner V3s). When compiling the kernel I ensured that cfg80211 (Prism2.5/3 USB driver) and the RTL8723BS driver would be compiled into module. (The branch pulled: `git clone -b zero-5.2.y --depth 1 https://github.com/Lichee-Pi/linux.git`)

The file system is built with `debootstrap`: `sudo debootstrap --foreign --verbose --arch=armhf buster rootfs http://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/debian/`

The generated `cfg80211.ko` and `r8723bs.ko` are moved into the file system built before. And the firmware (rtl8723bs_nic.bin) is placed in /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/.

After launch the board:

```bash
root@localhost:~# ls
cfg80211.ko  r8723bs.ko
```

```bash
root@localhost:~# insmod cfg80211.ko 
[   42.612104] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   42.681722] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   42.691307] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[   42.700084] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
```

```bash
root@localhost:~# insmod r8723bs.ko
[ 7717.536447] r8723bs: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 7717.585596] RTL8723BS: module init start
[ 7717.589700] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs v4.3.5.5_12290.20140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[ 7717.596742] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[ 7717.620428] pnetdev = cdfb5f40
[ 7717.659867] RTL8723BS: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[ 7717.679508] RTL8723BS: module init ret =0
```

```bash
root@localhost:~# ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20480  bytes 1884160 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20480  bytes 1884160 (1.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0c:cf:89:32:c3:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```bash
root@localhost:~# sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
[ 7727.036681] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

It seems that the firmware is acquired normally, and the module is successfully recognized before the infomation `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted` (Perhaps). But wlan0 could not be asserted. It seems like an authority issue but the `root` has been used.

Maybe `wlan0` should be shown in `ifconfig` without `-a` when successfully asserted.

Thank you.